# Why do I always get 'high tourist demand' notice in SimCity?

Tags: simcity-2013

I got a notice that I had 'high tourist demand'.

I have built a municipal airport, a ferry terminal, a airship hangar and a bus terminal.

How can I improve?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've made an impressive network of commuter services, but you need something for tourists to *do*. I suggest an Expo center, though this is very expensive!